# Emptying out Mitzrayim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, passover-seder-hagada

If when the Jews left Egypt it says וינצלו את מצרים, they emptied out Mitzrayim, then where did all the silver and gold that the Egyptians had at the Yam Suf come from? And the spoils at the sea were far greater than what they took from Egypt?
I see that this question was asked by Menachem here [Where did the Egyptians get the wealth they brought to the sea?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/where-did-the-egyptians-get-the-wealth-they-brought-to-the-sea)  but I would like some sources for the answer.

Comment: An answer is provided with a source there?

Comment: @Ravbruk welcome! As your question is a duplicate it will likely be flagged for deletion. If you would like clarification then I suggest posting a comment beneath the existing answer.